# Does the period of hosting impact website rankings on search engines?

Tags: seo, web-hosting

Does the period of hosting impact website rankings on search engines? If so, what should be the minimum period one should host?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Do you mean how long would you expect before your site appears in search engines? Are you thinking of hosting a site which will disappear after a while?

Answer (score 3):

The period of hosting has nothing to do with the ranking on various search engines. It's the content and time for which your website remains online. As soon as your site goes offline and web crawling bots found it, the reindexing starts.

So, in real sense taking an yearly hosting or monthly payable hosting has no effect on ranking.

Answer (score 1):

Period of hosting does not, according to my experiences or anything I've read, have any effect on SEO.

What you may be thinking of is the length of time a domain has been registered. Some people think that the length a domain has been registered has an effect. See https://www.quora.com/Search-Engine-Optimization-SEO/Does-domain-registration-length-impact-SEO for some discussion on the topic. Personally I've not seen this have any effect - or any effect it might have is dwarfed by the normal good-content practices.

Comment: Quora now requires login to see answers. Please excerpt actual relevant bits if you plan to use them as a source, not just link.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on search engine you are talking.

You can read about the PageRank algorithm of Google. I don't think they will analyze how old a site is to meter his quality.

But off course, a point to consider is: new sites aren't crawled till the search engine robot found it.

Answer (score 0):

how long the site has actualy been hosted i think has little to do with it, as many sites can just be hosted with sedo parking or an apache start page for years before there is a website present, if your referring to the age of the domain, ie how long ago the domain was registered matt cutts from google has an interesting done a small video on it here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1_1NQWQJ2Q

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming what you're actually asking about is the age of the *domain* and not hosting:]

Here's Matt Cutts: [How does Google determine domain age, and is it important for ranking?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=-pnpg00FWJY).
The short version is that domain age doesn't get measured *directly* but more as a sort of function of actually becoming "part of" the web, ie. getting links. Also, it's not very important, so don't worry about it.

As far as minimum period, you're never going to get a number from Google. After buyding your domain, throw up a holding page with some basic information as soon as possible, and maybe get a few links to it if you can. By the time you're ready to launch, it'll have existed and been indexed for a few months, and that's good in itself.